# B2B transaction meta data to database

Tags: ibm-datapower

Using soap input we can query b2b metadata .
Sample query:

I want response of above to checked at Datapower regularly and sent to MQ Queue or soap node of broker...

Want to log complete b2b transactions meta data to database once response pass to Mq queue or soap node of broker it is easy to log to database.

But how get the response for every transaction in B2B Transaction viewer..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set up Processing Policies for your partners (both Internal and External) where you dump out data.
If you need to add AS2/ebMS MDN's you can grab those in the Response rule (Server to Client). 
If you need the final AS2/MDN envelopes you need to proxy the messages through a XML Firewall or MPGW as you won't get the final envelopes otherwise...